# Displaying grouped nested arrays using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am trying to group and display a list of names under teams from an ajax call using Vue JS.

Here is the original object:

```
0 {  name: Bob Sinclair
 teamname: Francs
 email: bob.sinclair@test.com
 job: Product Manager
 type: Team Member
  }
1 {  name: Neil Jones
 teamname: Dream Team
 email: neil.jones@test.com
 job: Developer
 type: Team Member
  }
2 {  name: Jim Cairns
 teamname: Dream Team
 email: jim.cairns@test.com
 job: Developer
 type: Team Member
  }
```

I have grouped the data by "teamname" using the following function:

```
                function groupBy(collection, property) {
                var i = 0, val, index,
                    values = [], result = [];
                for (; i < collection.length; i++) {
                    val = collection[i][property];
                    index = values.indexOf(val);
                    if (index > -1)
                        result[index].push(collection[i]);
                    else {
                        values.push(val);
                        result.push([collection[i]]);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
```

This gives me the following output in the console:

```
0 { 0 { name: Bob Sinclair
        teamname: Francs
        email: bob.sinclair@test.com
        job: Product Manager
        type: Team Member
      }
1 { 0 { name: Neil Jones
        teamname: Dream Team
        email: neil.jones@test.com
        job: Developer
        type: Team Member
      }
    1 { name: Jim Cairns
        teamname: Dream Team
        email: jim.cairns@test.com
        job: Developer
        type: Team Member
      }
```

My issue is getting this to display using "v-for".
I want to be able to have a card for each "teamname" with a list of "names" underneath.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that your grouped data are called teams:

Then your template code should be:

```
<div class="team" v-for="team in teams" :key="team[0].teamname">
    <p> {{ team[0].teamname }} </p>
    <div class="teammates" v-for="teammate in team" :key="teammate.name">
        {{ teammate.name }}
        // other infos for teammate
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing!! and so simple. Could not get my head around this at all. Thank you very much!